# Will this algorithm stop before time?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, alternative-proof

For every $n \in \mathbb N$, let's define $a_0 = 0$, $$\begin{cases} a_{i+1} = 2a_i + 1 \pmod {2^n},  &\text{if it never appeared before} \\ a_{i+1} = 2a_i \pmod {2^n},&  \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

if both $2a_i + 1 \pmod {2^n}$ and $2a_i \pmod {2^n}$ are already in the sequence, the algorithm stops

for example with $n=3$, we have $$0, 1, 3, 7, 6, 5, 2, 4$$
for $n=4$, we have $$0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 14, 13, 11, 6, 12, 9, 2, 5, 10, 4, 8$$

The goal is to show that, for every $n$, every number between $0$ and $2^n - 1$ will be generated.

(Of course every number generated will be distinct, but you have to show that the algorithm does not stop before)

I have a somewhat lengthy proof of this, but I would like to see other (more elegant) proofs.

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

I came up with the sequence trying to solve the following problem:

Show that for every $n$, there exist a string $A$ long $2^n + n - 1$ digits so that every binary sequence of $n$ digits can be extracted as subsequence of consecutives digits of $A$.

For example, with $n=3$, $A = 0001110100$ is long $2^3 + 3 - 1$ and we can find $000, 001, 010, 100, 101, 111, \text{etc}$ as subsequences of $A$.

One can see that the fact that the algorithm does not stop is equivalent to the existence of $A$

Comment: Another interesting question is how to characterize the permutation of $[0, 2^n-1]$ that this generates - it's got some commonality with both Grey codes and Linear Feedback Shift Register sequences.  It's clear that it starts with the numbers $2^i-1$, $0\leq i\leq n$ and ends with the numbers $2^i$, $1\leq i\lt n$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I tried to search it on OEIS, but nothing came up. (anyhow, the sequence does not end like that, I added an example. It is true, though, that the last element is $2^{n-1}$)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I added some infos on how I stumbled upon it; maybe it helps to characterize it :)

Comment: If you don't require minimality, [de Bruijn sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) are relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Show that for every $n$, there exist a string $A$ long $2^n+n−1$ digits so that every binary sequence of n digits can be extracted as subsequence of consecutives digits of $A$.

Such a string is guaranteed to exist by the [De Bruijn sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction) (setting $k=2$). The proof is rather elegant: construct a graph whose nodes are all the integer from $0$ to $2^{n-1} - 1$, add edges from $i$ to $j$ iff $i \mod 2^{n-2} = \lfloor j/4 \rfloor$ (that is, the last $(n-2)$ digits of the binary representation of $i$ is the same with the first $(n-2)$ digits of the binary representation fo $j$), and a Eulerian path in this graph constitutes to such a sequence. The existence of a Eulerian path in this graph is guaranteed by the properties of the graph -- if $n > 2$, then the graph is both connected and all nodes have even degree.

Comment: This. Is. Awesome! How did you come up with that? Brilliant

Comment: It's the same proof with the one in wikiped... I think?